# Best options for deploying a Ruby standalone script and dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

for a Ruby standalone script what Rails like deployment features such as Gemfile / "bundle install" etc

that is assuming you are developing a Ruby script that you want to test and then deployment, and perhaps ship to others, what Rails like deployment approach would you use for say:

a) GEM - marking GEM requirements & having them installed as required - e.g. Rails "Gemfile" where you mark what gems you need and then "bundle install" to install them

b) File Require - automatically loading *.rb files if they are in your script directory (I'm thinking of in Rails where if you put a class file in the apps/model directory Rails automatically load/require's the file for you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my humble opinion, a gem is the way to go. Bundler makes it easy to get started; it starts a skeleton for you when you run the command…

```
bundle gem <GEM_NAME>
```

[Take a look](http://gembundler.com/rubygems.html). As long as you specify your dependencies in your gem's `.gemspec` file, and somebody installs your packaged gem (they won't need bundler, just RubyGems' `gem` command), the dependencies will be installed as gems along with it.

Comment: oh thanks Ben - this sounds like a good idea - what I was actually specifically asking about was how to handle dependencies for my script which uses other GEMs (c.f. how to package my own script itself), including during development of my script.  Or perhaps this is what you already understood?

Answer (score 4):

depends on whether it's a tool you expect people to use on every host they find it on or not. also depends on whether the tool can be shared with pubic repos.

if it just has to work, without worrying about whether you've installed the gems via bundler already or not, you can use something like the following from within your standalone script to install gems if not already present (be mindful of system vs. user ruby):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'

def install_gem(name, version=Gem::Requirement.default)
  begin
    gem name, version
  rescue LoadError
    print "ruby gem '#{name}' not found, " <<
      "would you like to install it (y/N)? : "
    answer = gets
    if answer[0].downcase.include? "y"
      Gem.install name, version
    else
      exit(1)
    end
  end
end

# any of the following will work...
install_gem 'activesupport'
install_gem 'activesupport', '= 4.2.5'
install_gem 'activesupport', '~> 4.2.5'

require 'active_support/all'

...
```